# Retrieve error message when 'BAD error_here' is sent from the imap4 server

Tags: delphi, imap, indy

I have a `TIdImap4` client and I sometimes receive this from an imap server :

```
C3 BAD Mailbox parameter is invalid.
```

I've managed to fix the request from my client, but the only way I could read this error message was in the indy function :

```
function TIdIMAP4.GetInternalResponse(const ATag: String; 
  AExpectedResponses: array of String;  
  ASingleLineMode: Boolean; ASingleLineMayBeSplit: Boolean {= False}): string;
```

, but when the result of `function TIdIMAP4.StatusMailBox(const AMBName: String; AMB: TIdMailBox; const AStatusDataItems: array of TIdIMAP4StatusDataItem): Boolean;` is False I don't know how to access the error message. I've tried the properties :

```
- imap4Client.LastCmdResult.Text.Text 
- imap4Client.LastCmdResult.FormattedReply.Text
```

but there is no error message in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking in the `TIdReplyIMAP4(imap4Client.LastCmdResult).Extra` property.